# Emojis for other programs

Tags: 16.04, emoji

I just installed EmojiOne in hopes of my unicode emojis working on Discord, but I've been disappointed, as its displaying the emojis by a white/black border (look in screenshot)

[image]

Is there anything that I can do to get them to work?
Thanks in advance, and happy holidays! :)

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/q/736472/367990

Comment: Related: [Color emoji problem in Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968271/color-emoji-problem-in-ubuntu-17-10)